# Sharing x-axis between two plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I have the following time series with `ts` as index and column named `metric_value`:

```
ts
2020-01-01 00:00:00    1225917
2020-01-01 01:00:00     670334
2020-01-01 02:00:00     668207
2020-01-01 03:00:00     576977
2020-01-01 04:00:00     713490
Name: metric_value, dtype: int32
```

I'm trying to plot this time series and mark the outlier data points with a red circle. The outliers' indexes are in this list:

```
idxs=['2020-06-06 19:00:00', '2020-07-04 19:00:00', '2020-08-08 19:00:00']
```

The following shows how I'm plotting the data for June.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex="all", sharey="all", figsize=(12,4))
ax = ts.loc['2020-06-01 00:00:00':'2020-06-30 23:00:00']['metric_value'].plot(title='June')
ax = ts.loc[[idx for idx in idxs if idx>'2020-06-01 00:00:00' and idx<'2020-06-30 23:00:00']]['metric_value'].plot(style='.')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
```

For month June, there is one outlier at this index=`2020-06-06 19:00:00`. The issue is that the plot doesn't show this data point on the correct location. It shows it on the first location which is zero! I think it happens because these two plots are not sharing the x-axis and as the plot shows only the second plots' axis. How can I fix it?
I tried [this solution](https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/28015/a-plot-of-2-functions-on-shared-x-axis-) but it didn't work!

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with the data provided. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue as follow:

```
ts['flag'] = False
for idx in idxs:
   ts.loc[idx, 'flag'] = True
    
x = list(np.where(ts.loc['2020-06-01 00:00:00':'2020-06-30 23:00:00']['flag'])[0])
y = ts.iloc[np.where(ts.loc['2020-06-01 00:00:00':'2020-06-30 23:00:00']['flag'])]['metric_value']    
    
ts.loc['2020-06-01 00:00:00':'2020-06-30 23:00:00']['metric_value'].plot(title='June', figsize=(12,4), x_compat=True)
if len([idx for idx in idxs if idx>'2020-06-01 00:00:00' and idx<'2020-06-30 23:00:00'])>0:
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=4,)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the two axes in the Pandus plot can be achieved in the following ways Does the following answer solve your problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-09-30', freq='1H')
value = np.random.randint(5000, 30000, size=6553)
ts = pd.DataFrame({'ts': pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'metric_value':value})
ts.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idxs=['2020-06-06 19:00:00', '2020-07-04 19:00:00', '2020-08-08 19:00:00']

# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey="all", figsize=(12,4))
ts.loc['2020-06-01 00:00:00':'2020-06-30 23:00:00',['metric_value']].plot(title='June')
ts.loc[[idx for idx in idxs if idx>'2020-06-01 00:00:00' and idx<'2020-06-30 23:00:00']]['metric_value'].plot(style='.', secondary_y=['ts', 'metric_value'])

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: no it doesn't work :( still plots the dot on the x=0

Comment: Have you copied and run all my code? If you still get an error, maybe it's an environmental issue?